# CiviEvent - Update/Add people or events after initial registration

Tags: wordpress, civievent

Is there any way to have someone update their registration? We have a yearly conference and it's not always know what all the addons are going to be when registration goes live.

Think golf tournament, or private dinner or things like that.

We also have spouse/kids that can attend and many times, they aren't added in the initial registration.

Answer (score 1):

No, allowing contacts to change event selections themselves is, frustratingly, a missing feature. If you're interested in helping to implement this, either with contributions of code or funding, I'm sure others would be interested in working with you on this (I know it's a feature that I wish we had).

If it's just a matter of adding more options and not removing, as long as you have "Allow same email and multiple registrations?" checked, they can register again to add the additional options. The downside there is you can't merge the two event registrations on the backend. For the other participants, they can just register again for them, though that's less than ideal as well.

You can, of course, have people get in touch and then you can edit their registrations on the back end and charge them the additional amount required there.

Welcome to CiviCRM, by the way.

Comment: I have tech skills, but not much time (I am a volunteer for the non-profit), and we do have some budget if needed. Of course, we would release to the community.

It's a very missing feature.

I will write up a more detailed RFP and problem list. I need this done fairly quickly though.

Comment: Sounds good. The place to post that would be https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues
I'd be happy to discuss implementation details, but to get you started, we already have Self-Service Registration Update (aka Transfer or Cancel) and we have the backend Change Selections form, so step one would be sticking those together so that contacts could update their selections. Then step two would be handling the additional payment and/or refund. But I think doing step one first would make sense, leaving the payment/refund for manual processing at first.

Comment: I think I need to clarify the problem. 
Person 1 registers in Sept. Then in December we announce there is a city tour for $75. As it is right now, person 1 can't add only the city tour in December. If it has to be done manually, that is a non-starter. We don't have staff, we have volunteers.

This is not a strange thing as most events allow people to modify registrations after they have already signed up.

Comment: BTW, https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/event/-/issues/new is a 404, so I can't add anything there.

Comment: You put it in the right place. Did you find that link somewhere? It shouldn't be.

Comment: Yes, when I went to report an issue. This should either redirect or put a page up saying it's archived. Not 404.

https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues

New issue drop down